# wireless doesn't work after update

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 on a new Compaq cq58 laptop. After installing Ubuntu wifi dind't work, but following instructions on the forum I could install the drivers and make it work....now after updating wireless stopped working...I don't know what to do now...

```
~$ sudo rfkill list all


0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
```

Comment: Sometimes the driver needs compiling every fresh kernel. Depends what instructions you followed...

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! *"following instructions on the forum"* Please include these instructions as it is very relevant to your question/issue. And have you tried re-running these steps?

Answer (score -1):

I got the answer [here](http://www.samundra.com.np/wireless-driver-stopped-working-after-upgrade-ubuntu/1074) maybe you'll receive when you update that the key is not available key run this `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8B48AD6246925553`

in my case 8B48AD6246925553 is the key that I received with the error after update

Comment: it's not immediately clear how this answers the question. please provide a summary of the info at the link.